# AJAX post; variable always returns null

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm wondering if I got something wrong in my code. I want to do 2 AJAX posts. If the first one is successful it should execute the second one. Here you can see the code I have:

```
var lat = $('#lat').val();
var lng = $('#lng').val();
var test;
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyPostalCodes",
    type: "GET",
    data: {lat: lat, lng: lng, radius: 20, maxRows: 100, country: "CH", username: "bbag8274"},
    success: function(scriptData, textStatus, jqXHR){

        // second
        test = scriptData;
        alert($.parseXML( test ));
        $.ajax({
            url: "test_data.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {xmldata: test},
            contentType: "text/xml",
            success: function(secondScriptData, textStatus, jqXHR){
                alert(secondScriptData);
            },

            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('Unknown error, report it!');
            }
        });

        // end second

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('fail');
    }
});
```

I created the `var test` for testing what it alerts me. And thats the point. It always alerts me `null`. So my parameter `scriptData` is always `null`. I can't figure out why. Where have I made a mistake or is there a mistake at all?

Suggestions are appreciated :)

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Comment: ok sorry, didn't saw you were trying to alert it inside success callback. So the first comment (deleted) was more accurate, are you returning something from findNearbyPostalCodes ?

Comment: Which alert is failing? I see a few of them in there. And I got back results when I ran that from console and the alert inside the first success showed [object Document] as expected if `$.parseXML` is removed. Otherwise it throws invalid xml error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API you are calling is returning an XML object. It has the correct `content-type` header for XML and you aren't overriding the parsing engine for jQuery. This means that jQuery is parsing the XML document into a DOM before passing it into `scriptData`.

You then pass that value to `$.parseXML`. This is a method that takes a string input and parses into a DOM.

Since a DOM isn't a string, it will be converted to one (`"[Object document]"`). This is not valid XML, so the XML parser will give you `null`.

Don't use `$.parseXML`.

---

You will then have another problem.

`data: {xmldata: test}` will also cause the DOM to be converted to the string `"[Object document]"` so you won't get the XML document in the next request.

If you want the raw text of the response, use `jqXHR.responseText` instead of `scriptData`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I don't use `$.parseXML` I get `[object Document]`. But I want to have a string. Is there another encode function which I have to use?